# Unable to find native library

Tags: android-ndk

Android cannot find the code of my app which is in a .so file.

I have a pure NDK project (C++ project, no java) that builds a .so file (libdygd.so). In release mode this file is found during startup but during debug mode it does not. The CMake Debug mode build (launched from gradle) adds a suffix to the file (libdygdd.so).
In AndroidManifest.xml there is a line: 
If I change android:value="dygd" to android:value="dygdd" the debug build loads the .so (and app starts fine) but the release build does not work (the .so file is not found with this change).

Am I missing a setting to get the .so loader to automatically find *d.so files?

The file after building can be found here: 
./app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libdygdd.so

The AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.dygd">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="dygd" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I get this log output when starting the app on a device:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(18572): Process: com.example.dygd, PID: 18572
E/AndroidRuntime(18572): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dygd/android.app.NativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library dygd using classloader: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.dygd-VWbId7f-ZG7VzirT0GBJBA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.dygd-VWbId7f-ZG7VzirT0GBJBA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.dygd-VWbId7f-ZG7VzirT0GBJBA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]]
E/AndroidRuntime(18572): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library dygd using classloader: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.dygd-VWbId7f-ZG7VzirT0GBJBA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.dygd-VWbId7f-ZG7VzirT0GBJBA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.dygd-VWbId7f-ZG7VzirT0GBJBA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]]
W/ActivityManager( 1400):   Force finishing activity com.example.dygd/android.app.NativeActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing a setting to get the .so loader to automatically find *d.so files?

The `d` suffix is a convention of the library that you're using that the system does not no about. What you probably want to do is build the debug version with the same name and just differentiate based on whether you're using a debug or release build in Studio (gradle will automatically use the `RelWithDebInfo` or `Debug` CMake release types as necessary, I believe).

You might also be able to use a different manifest for each build flavor.

Alternatively, ditch the `NativeActivity` and use `System.loadLibrary` to handle this yourself. `NativeActivity` is really only useful for a small subset of apps (pretty much exclusively games, since they do all their own UI), so unless that applies to your app you'll have an easier time not using a `NativeActivity` anyway.